# I am using Django rest framework I want to use random in my views.py can someone help me

Tags: django, django-models, random, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django rest framework I want to use random in my views.py can someone help me
I want to make Questions in views.py to be random and here is my code

views.py

```
class QuizQuetionsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=QuizQuetionsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        quiz_id=self.kwargs['quiz_id']
        quiz=models.Quiz.objects.get(pk=quiz_id)
        return models.QuizQuetions.objects.filter(quiz=quiz)
        


class QuizChapterQuetionsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=QuizQuetionsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        quizChapter_id=self.kwargs['quizChapter_id']
        quizChapter=models.QuizChapter.objects.get(pk=quizChapter_id)
        return models.QuizQuetions.objects.filter(quizChapter=quizChapter)
```

this is my models.py

```
    #Quiz Model
class Quiz(models.Model):
    teacher=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='qize')
    title=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    detail=models.TextField()
    add_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return   f"{self.teacher}-{self.title}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="10.Quiz"

#QuizChapter Model
class QuizChapter(models.Model):
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    add_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return   f"{self.quiz}-{self.title}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="11.QuizChapter"


#QuizQuetions Model
class QuizQuetions(models.Model):
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    quizChapter=models.ForeignKey(QuizChapter,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    questions=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    A=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    B=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    C=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    D=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    right_ans=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    add_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return   f"{self.id}-{self.quizChapter}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="12.QuizQuetions"
```

I want to make both of them to be random

to get solutions to my problem

Comment: For ease of solution, would suggest you to limit to 1 classview and implement the solution that would be provided to other views.
Also, kindly put your models.py here.

Comment: I put my models.py above those are my models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) here for making the order of the queryset random, for example:

```
return models.QuizQuetions.objects.filter(quiz=quiz).order_by('?')
```